# DnD Image Upload using jQuery + PHP

Tags: php, jquery, fileapi, data-uri

I'm trying to set up a drag-and-drop uploading system for images, and I have no idea how to write the data to a file using PHP.

Currently, I am using `FileReader.readAsDataURL()` to retrieve a Data URI for the uploaded image, and store that in `var data`.

```
var base64_start = data.indexOf(',') + 1;
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'save_image.php',
    ...
    data : data.substring(base64_start)
});
```

Inside `save_image.php`:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $val) {
    $file = $key; 
    break;  
}

$binary = base64_decode($file);
$fh = fopen('images/test.png', 'w');
fwrite($fh, $binary);
```

I tried downloading `test.png` and it says the image is corrupted.

I've also tried using `imagecreatefromstring()`:

```
$binary = base64_decode($file);
$img = imagecreatefromstring($binary);
```

Comment: I found http://permadi.com/blog/2010/10/html5-saving-canvas-image-data-using-php-and-ajax/#viewSource ! I changed the 'Content-Type' header to 'application/upload', and had to change the fwrite mode to 'wb' for write binary. D'oh! But is there a way to POST stuff like a filename along with the binary data?